# Coinbase Pro Node.js API: How to get response using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, gdax-api

I'm using the [Coinbase Pro official Node.js client library](https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node).

How do I access the `response` object after [making a request using promises](https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node#using-promises)?

My use case: I'm calling `authedClient.getFills()` and want to use `response.headers['cb-after']` in my next request to get the next page of data. Ultimately, I'm trying to make a function called `getAllFills` that would get all the pages of fills (one after the other) for a specific product ID.

Comment: Have you tried the syntax of https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node#using-promises? In the example `products` is the response from the API

Comment: No, I hadn't tried it because I figured `products` was `data`. I just tried, and yes, `products` is `data` (the response body). I need the `response` object, which has the response headers, status code, etc.

Comment: if you want help with *your* code, shouldn't you put that in the question?

Comment: @JaromandaX I want help with their API, not my code.

Comment: *their API* is documented, as per your links ... how you are using *their API* is anyones guess - but if you think your question is somehow on topic, I guess with 53k reputation you'll probably get away with such a poor quality question

Comment: @JaromandaX their documentation doesn't answer my question. But, I was able to answer my own question by reading their source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To access the `response` object, you must use the [callback API](https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node#using-callbacks).

Their promise API doesn't expose the `response` object. You can see this if you look at the [`PublicClient.makeRequestCallback()` method in `/lib/clients/public.js` of the Coinbase Pro Node.js API source code on GitHub](https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node/blob/master/lib/clients/public.js#L91).